# Xml-Fo to keep justified text with same number of words in line as in left

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I wonna make justified text with Apache FOP to have same number of words as the text with left aligh.

[image: Here is how the left text and justify text looks like:]

The goal is to make the justified text to have exactly the same words on each line, as the one with align="left".

Comment: Have you written any XSL-FO? Then please show minimal but complete code samples to demonstrate the issue. Also tell us exactly which version of Apache FOP you use.

Comment: I'm using 2.6. The code for the text is simple:
<fo:block-container>
  <fo:block text-align="left">
    <fo:inline>Lorem Ipsum text here</fo:inline>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>

So i'm just changing the align from left to justify, but the justified text become with more words on a line, compared with the left one

Comment: The best way for us to test and suggest something is to use your exact text. Please consider posting a small, full XSL FO. No one is going to type in your Lorem ipsum text verbatim.

Comment: Hello, sure! <fo:block-container><fo:block text-align="left"><fo:inline>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</fo:inline></fo:block></fo:block-container>

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different formatter. If anything, one would assume that the justified text would yield *less* words per line or equal, not *more*.

I used this sample:

```
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block-container>
            <fo:block>Dolores vero dolor sed accusam ipsum tempor justo ipsum tempor lorem vel
                ipsum no. Ipsum dolor eleifend lorem ipsum dolor in takimata sit dolor. Sit et
                te te duo diam diam stet no assum invidunt illum lorem no. Augue amet clita no
                sit tempor nonumy nulla gubergren elitr liber magna ut facilisis eum et eos.
                Tempor magna accusam elitr sit voluptua et aliquyam ut consectetuer lorem et
                volutpat stet diam dolor voluptua consetetur amet. Eos magna stet. Ea dolore
                adipiscing eos et dolor dolore et magna nulla eleifend. Sed est at molestie
                dolore amet sit accusam nulla consetetur vero mazim sed kasd lobortis dolore.
                Amet ipsum sanctus duo nibh vero invidunt quis clita at dolores nonumy eum kasd
                vero illum eum eos est.</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
        <fo:block space-after="12pt"><fo:leader/></fo:block>
        <fo:block-container text-align="justify">
            <fo:block>Dolores vero dolor sed accusam ipsum tempor justo ipsum tempor lorem vel
                ipsum no. Ipsum dolor eleifend lorem ipsum dolor in takimata sit dolor. Sit et
                te te duo diam diam stet no assum invidunt illum lorem no. Augue amet clita no
                sit tempor nonumy nulla gubergren elitr liber magna ut facilisis eum et eos.
                Tempor magna accusam elitr sit voluptua et aliquyam ut consectetuer lorem et
                volutpat stet diam dolor voluptua consetetur amet. Eos magna stet. Ea dolore
                adipiscing eos et dolor dolore et magna nulla eleifend. Sed est at molestie
                dolore amet sit accusam nulla consetetur vero mazim sed kasd lobortis dolore.
                Amet ipsum sanctus duo nibh vero invidunt quis clita at dolores nonumy eum kasd
                vero illum eum eos est.</fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:flow>
```

I format with Apache FOP and it yields this (replicating what you get). Note you can see that justified text actually yields more words per line which means to me that justification is changing letter and word spacing so much so that it yields more words on a line.

[image]

I format with RenderX XEP and it yields this, which is what you expect. The justification just *increases* letter and word spacing in a pleasing manner so that the same number of words are on each line.

[image]

I would note that in my (totally biased as I work for RenderX) opinion, the original left justified text by RenderX is much better. The ragged right edges are much tighter and it is already fitting content even in a left-justification. RenderX is not merely word/space/word/space ... break because a word does not fit on the line. RenderX has an adjustment for line tightness that will already squeeze to fit even with left-justified text is a word's length at line end is within a certain threshold. FOP does not do this or it is not apparent that it does.

I tried modifying things like letter and word spacing with no success. Not sure you can report this as a "bug" because it really isn't. It is merely a difference in the core engine behavior.

Answer (score 0):

FOP may have implemented TeX line breaking too literally. I haven't seen a way to stop it from shrinking white-space.

FOP implements the TeX line-breaking algorithm, as does AH Formatter (https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-tech.html#line-breaking). The TeX algorithm (http://www.eprg.org/G53DOC/pdfs/knuth-plass-breaking.pdf) allows spaces to have both 'stretchability' and 'shrinkability'.

`word-spacing` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#word-spacing) is the XSL property that, unsurprisingly, controls the spacing between words. CSS also has `word-spacing`, but the XSL `word-spacing` can be a `<space>`, with `.minimum`, `.optimum`, and `.maximum` components. As I read the `word-spacing` definition, the default `normal` value means that a space should be the width of a space.

`text-align="justify"` is defined as expanding the contents (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#text-align).

So as I read the spec, `text-align="justify"` should give the same words per line as `text-align="start"` (the XSL default value), as in the Antenna House sample below and @KevinBrown's sample. Squeezing in more words per line should require a negative `word-spacing.minimum` value, as below.

[image: Sample text formatted three ways]